# Creating a dynamic table with movable rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to create a table of items like [this invoice](https://www.invoiceninja.com/invoices/create) in Ruby on Rails, any hints on where I can start? I am fairly new to JavaScript. Also is there a gem that can do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the Nested Form gem. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 2):

I cant give a full example as your request is fairly generic. There are about 1000 possibilities to do this: use raw javascript, use jQuery, use jQuery Datatables, use Js + AngularJS etc. The only common thing is that a JSON backend on the server side is also needed, so your javascript can communicate with your server and save the data.

However, I would recommend the jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin.
A starting point would be the ["adding rows example"](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html). Also, check out the [railscasts databable tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast) for details on JSON backend.

Comment: can the jQuery DatabTables plugin work like it does in that [invoice link](https://www.invoiceninja.com/invoices/create) using js, where you can enter the select the item in a select2 gem dropdown box and display the price related to the item and then enter a quantity. then it will update the total price for example?

Comment: not automatically... you have to write javascript to do it.

Comment: how would I create a button that when clicked for example, it will add more fields for items? like a new row. As in that invoice, one appears automatically if entering the previous line